# Detect the operator message during calling in android

Tags: android, android-studio, phone-call

Generally whenever a outgoing call is made, if the receiver number is switch off, dialer will hear "number is switch off", 
or if the receiver is talking with some other person, dialer will hear "number is busy", etc.

I want to make a package which detects following call state when the outgoing call is made and network opearator says some message -

Toast "busy" when the operator alert "number is busy". 
Toast "switch-off" when the number is switch off. 
Toast "line-busy" when the receiver is talking with someone while dialing. 
Toast "outside coverage" when the receiver is out of coverage. 
Toast "incorrect" when the dialer dials an incorrect number 
Toast "Noti" when the operator sends rest messages like "low balance, offers", etc.

For example person X calls person Y,
if person Y number is switch off, person X will hear that "Number is switch off" from opearator, so I want to detect what the operator says while dialing a number.

I know it's bit difficult, but I request community to help me, I stuck on these from last 3 months.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/arekolek/simple-phone

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it. But with this I can't able to detect the operator message.

Comment: what u want to create by doing that ?

Comment: u can record call and then apply some ML over the audio and find out the call state

Comment: i don't think there is some default support or API in android to find out the call state

Comment: I also thought for doing that but it takes some time to classify the audio, and might happen if the content of the audio alert in some other manner or in different language my model will fail, isn't there is any type of flag through which I can detect state?

Comment: So is there any alternative through which I can detect the state?

Comment: there is no such flag as it is a part of severe user privacy

Comment: what u want to create by doing that ? don't waste your time. better learn something high standard stuff and work upon it. 2020 is coming and u r still working on a calling app. i m considering u as my brother

Comment: ok, thanks, might be someone also face the similar problem, let's wait for others.

Comment: I just try some experiment, collecting data from operator and performing some data science operation on it. One thing more I just want to know what the opearator says when dialer not able to connect with receiver, and I don't think it can lead to severe privacy leak of user.

Comment: ur social media ?

Comment: you can contact me on hangouts - csetanmayjain@gmail.com

Comment: i sent u a message. check ur hangouts